# Getting a full RSS feed

Tags: php, rss

I'm testing a feed which I plan to later consume in my application. When viewing it in the browser, it shows only the last 7 items.

- Do feeds behave different when consumed from a program?
- If not, how do I view the full feed from the first item to the last item? I'd like to at least see it in the browser first

Comment: Feeds normally contain the latest x items, not every item ever created/posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do feeds behave different when consumed from a program?

The browser is a program; technicalities aside, it's theoretically possible that a server would respond differently if the user agent was not a browser. It's not very likely though.

Check if the feed accepts a `page` url parameter or similar. If not, you'll have to find another feed.

Answer (score 2):

Your RSS feed only contains seven items.  (Browsers will not trim RSS feeds)

You need to find a bigger RSS feed.